# Capitalize the first letter of each string

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string, but it says `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'i'` . My logic looks fine but surely the way I'm doing this is not right. Any suggestions.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  var word = str.split(" ");
  // console.log(word[0][0]);
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length - 1; i++) {
    word[i][0] = word[i][0].toUpperCase();
  }
  console.log(word);
  return word;
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Comment: If you're not being paid by the character, try `s.replace(/\b\w/g,s=>s.toUpperCase())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like so: (see comments in code)

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  str=str.toLowerCase();
  var word = str.split(" ");
  for (var i=0; i < word.length; i++) {  // you don't need -1 here as you had
    word[i] = word[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word[i].slice(1); // see changes in this line
  }
  console.log(word);
  return word;
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Comment: what does slice(1)do ?

Comment: @AhsanAlii in this case it will remove the first letter (the lowercased one) which gets added with the uppercased one.

Answer (score 2):

Strings have a *replace* method that accepts a function:

```js
var s = 'foo bar fum i am sparticus 23!!';

console.log(s.replace(/\b\w/g, function(s){return s.toUpperCase()}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly convert your string into what you want by inbuilt array function.
Using map function you will get it directly no need to run for loop.

```
("I'm a little tea pot")
.split(" ")
.map(function(d){
 return d[0].toUpperCase()+d.substring(1,d.length)
}).join(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `split` and `map` functions to achieve this.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().split(" ").map(function(word) {
    var _word = word.split("");
    _word[0] = _word[0].toUpperCase();
    return _word.join("");
  }).join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 1):

With split, array map and reduce:

```js
var str = "I'm a little tea pot";
var res = str.split(" ")
             .map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1))
             .reduce((m, o) => { m = m + " " + o; return m }, "")
console.log(res);
```

Join can be also used instead of reduce:

```js
    var str = "I'm a little tea pot";
    var res = str.split(" ")
                 .map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1))
                 .join(" ");
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function to create an array of modified words and `join` to recreate the string

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  var word = str.split(" ");

  var x = word.map(function(item) {
    return item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.substring(1, item.length);
  }).join(" ");
  return x
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Using only CSS

```css
#test {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<div id="test"> I'm a little tea pot</div>
```